# Really weird "redraw behavior" with anchor links, twitter bootstrap fixed-navbar and affix plugin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing an extremely weird behavior when using Twitter Bootstrap's affix plugin, fixed navbar, and anchor links together. I'm going to attempt to explain my problem but it's kind of difficult to put into words, so please forgive me if I'm not the clearest.

I have a `navbar-fixed-top` at the top of my page. Under that I have a `.container` div. Inside there I have two `div.spans` (`span4` and `span8`). Inside `span4` is a `div.well` that has the `affix-top` class applied to it (so it gets a fixed position and "sticks" where it's at). Inside my `span8` I have a bunch of content.

Inside the `well` div there is a `nav-list`. This list gets populated with `li`/`a` elements based on items in the `span8` (I have a little script that does this). The links are anchors, so they point to elements on the page (`#myId`, `#myIdTwo`, etc). All this works wonderfully. My list is there, the links are clickable, they take me to my elements. Great.

However, not great. Sometimes, when I click one of the links, I go to my anchor in the `span8` but the page doesn't seem to refresh properly. I sometimes see strange white "boxes". Or the content inside the span will show partly above the fixed `nav-header`. Sometimes half of the `nav-list` disappears.. but then comes back (sort-of) if I move my mouse around it. Like you used to see in some old Windows applications that were getting bogged down.

You can see for yourself here: http://jaylach.github.com/lutra. You may need to click some of the nav links a few times before you see the issue.

I've been struggling with this all day and I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out. I've taken out the affixes, I've taken out the fixed top navbar, I've taken out my `z-index`. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Does anyone, anywhere, have any clue as to what could be causing this? I would really appreciate any advice you guys could give.

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a WebKit bug.

add  `-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);` to both `.navbar-fixed-top` and `.affix`

both styles are defined in **bootstrap.min.css**. So override these 2 styles in your **main.css** as:

```
.affix,.navbar-fixed-top {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! You must have better google foo than me, because my searches were turning up nothing :)

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you give some information about where you found this fix / a bug registration page?

Comment: I dont remember the source I taken.. can you share your code online

Comment: I thought I was going to lose my mind fixing this.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: I almost thought my PC not catching up with it :) Thanks @aju worked great!